# How can I re-insert a paper guide that came out of my LaserJet printer's feeder tray?

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer, hp-laserjet, multi-function-printer

I have an HP LaserJet multifunction printer. It has two paper trays: Tray 1 is really just a door on the front that folds out and allows you to manually feed in sheets of varying sizes, while Tray 2 is the normal drawer that you fill with paper. And I have an unusual problem with Tray 1.

The door has two plastic paper guides, which are adjustable grey tabs that move in unison. So when you widen the paper guide on the right side, the left one moves the same amount in the other direction. My problem is that one of these paper guides, along with another plastic piece that accompanies it, came loose. In their loose state I was unable to close the Tray 1 door. So I wiggled them around until, eventually, they came out of the door completely. Here they are pictured below.

[image: paper guide pieces]

[image: door missing one paper guide]

As you can see, the door now only has one paper guide present on the right side. As best I can tell, miraculously, the plastic pieces appear to be intact and undamaged. But is it possible to re-insert them? Or are there any professionals who do printer repair that I could hire to re-insert it?

Comment: the white plastic with toots should go from under neath, the grey one from the top. the 2 plusses from the gray one should slide in the guides in the white parts. Other than that, hard to tell you how to do it.

Comment: are you mechanically inclined?

Comment: There are **many** videos demonstrating printer disassembly and reassembly in *detail*. Search on your **specific model**.